Getting "ErrorAction$ErrorId: edf4f356-929c-4720-a57f-b2bdef027f2c" error from Jenkins when trying to extract information from a child job
I have a use case where I want to extract information from a Child job in the parent job.
This is my pipeline script:
pipeline {
  agent any
    stages {
    stage('Validate Other Job') {
        steps {
            script {
                echo "triggerring build"
                   def triggeredJob = build job: 'Pipeline1'
                   def logs = triggeredJob.rawBuild.getLog(100)
                   echo "Logs '$logs'"
                   }
                }
            }
       }
}

Output: When 'Pipeline1' job status is: SUCCESS
It prints the logs
Issue: When 'Pipeline1' job status is: FAILURE or UNSTABLE
It throws error:
Build Pipeline1 #18 completed: FAILURE
   [Pipeline] }
   [Pipeline] // script
   [Pipeline] }
   [Pipeline] // stage
   [Pipeline] }
   [Pipeline] // node
   [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
   Pipieline1 #18 completed with status FAILURE (propagate: false to ignore)
  org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.actions.ErrorAction$ErrorId: edf4f356-929c-4720- 
  a57f-b2bdef027f2c
  Finished: FAILURE

My use case is to get the logs when Build fails/unstable and check that weather a particular string is available in the logs. If yes, then trigger a mail.
Child job is a dummy job:
pipeline {
agent any

stages {
    stage('Hello') {
        steps1 { // step1 for marking the build fail for testing
            echo 'Hello World'
        }
      }
    }
  }

Note: If I use, propagate: false, then it says:
"Scripts not permitted to use method hudson.model.Run getLog int."

By default the downstream build failure causes the upstream build failure, so you don't even get to the log parsing. To disable it pass the propagate: false parameter to the build step. If you read the log carefully it tells you that.

If I add propogate: false, then it says: Scripts not permitted to use method hudson.model.Run getLog int.

Congrats, you are actually got to the code you want to run! It doesn't run, but I believe we have resolved your original question :)

No, the issue is in retrieving child job logs when child job status is "Failure" or "Unstable".  In that case, it still gives same error which is mentioned in subject line of the question.

I believe it's a different error. The one you are getting now is from the script-security plugin. You can accept this answer and I will be more than happy to help you resolve your next question or we can leave it here.
